# Move files with Apache Camel to different directories depending on how many files are found

Tags: apache-camel, race-condition

A process should output one and only one file, it things go wrong it could result in zero or a few files in the output directory.

I want to pick up the file(s) and move them to directory A if there was one file and to directory B if more files were found. (And send a mail to some admin).

```
// fileCounter and FileNameFilter use same utility class for filtering!
from(config.getFrom())
    .to("bean:bean:fileCounter?method=fileCountInHeader(*)")
    .choice()
        .when(simple("${header.NumberOfFiles} == 0"))
            .to("bean:grootboekMutatiesMailHandler?method=createMailNoFile(*)")
        .when(simple("${header.NumberOfFiles} == 1"))
            .filter().method(new FileNameFilter(), getFilterBy())
            .to(config.getA()))
            .to("bean:grootboekMutatiesMailHandler?method=createMailSuccess(*,${header.FileNamesList})")
        .when(simple("${header.NumberOfFiles} > 1"))
            .filter().method(new FileNameFilter(), getFilterBy())
            .to(config.getB())
            .to("bean:grootboekMutatiesMailHandler?method=createMailManyFiles(*,${header.FileNamesList})").endChoice().end();
```

If the camel route starts from file, counting the number of files will be done for each file in turn, so the last file will always be transferred to directory A.

What i really want is list the files at the start of the route, count them and then only transfer these files to the appropriate directory. If a file is added, it should be neglegted, if a file is removed an error should be thrown.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you count the number of files in the bean, but you could instead use the **Camel Exchange property `CamelBatchSize`** that returns the number of files read from the directory in one polling.

> This only works if you can make sure that on every file polling you get **all** files from **only one** processing.

Another approach would be to use a timer to trigger in a given interval and then use your counter Java bean to count the files and delegate to dedicated routes for the three cases.

Something like (pseudo-code)

```
from(timer:countFiles?yourOptions)
    .bean(counterBean)
    .choose
        .when(0 files)
            .to(direct:noFile)
        .when(1 file)
            .to(direct:OneFile)
        .otherwise
            .to(direct:TooMuchFiles)
    .end()
```

In the direct routes you have various possibilities to consume the files:

- If you are not interested in the content, but you want to **just move** the files, you can use a bean that does this with Java code
- If you want to **consume a single file** to get its content, you can use the [pollEnrich EIP](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/eips/pollEnrich-eip.adoc)
- If pollEnrich is getting too clumsy because you want to **consume a lot of files**, you can write a dedicated route with a from-file (file poller) that is not started (autoStart=false). The you can use the [Controlbus](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/controlbus-component.adoc) to start and stop this route on demand from the direct routes.

Comment: FileCounter is a plain old java bean that uses java.io.File.list() and a filter to get all files that should be moved. My problem is i want to do the counting just once. After doing the count, the 'move' routes should kick off. I dont know how to organise this. I want to have one route that does the counting and then another, that starts immedeatly after, that moves the files.

Comment: Yeah, consuming files and inspect the directory you consume from works against each other. I updated my answer to better explain what I mean as alternative approach

Comment: Thanks @burki, do i have to somehow call a consumer by hand in direct:OneFile and direct:TooMuchFiles? Because these routes do not start from a fileEndpoint but from direct.

Comment: I have extended my answer with multiple possibilities to consume the files

Comment: I cannot find a decent example for controlbus, i have no idea how to tell the 'direct:TooMuchFiles' route to start consuming files from a directory. Just moving the files with a java bean is cumbersome is i would have to write classes to read and write from sftp, samba and what not.

Comment: You have to send a message to a controlbus URI. You can do that through a producer-template or simply with .to("controlbus:...") in a route. Have a look at this unit tests: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/controlbus/ControlBusStartRouteTest.java

Comment: I tried to use the controlbus, i'm now getting exceptions at startup. Need not be related, could be a typo. Will look at it again on Monday, thanks for all the help!

Comment: This answer put me in the right direction, but i had some trouble because i was filtering the files. I will post a working example, because i'm not sure i should modify your answer (related meta post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302816/should-i-edit-an-answer-if-it-is-incomplete)

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to implement a bean to count the files at the endpoint. Getting the number of files lined up for processing is possible because the File Consumer, including the ftp Consumer, is a [BatchConsumer](https://camel.apache.org/batch-consumer.html). This means that the Batch size can be extracted from the Exchange properties.

Here is a working example of routing files depending on batch size, the example is for a file consumer but also works for ftp.

```
    final String from = "file:data/input?filter=#myFilter";
    final String to1 = "file:data/output";
    final String toMany = "file:data/output2";

    from(from)
    .choice()
    .when(simple("${exchangeProperty[CamelBatchSize]} == 1"))
     .to(to1)
    .when(simple("${exchangeProperty[CamelBatchSize]} > 1"))
      .to(toMany);
```

Note that **any filters should be set on the 'from' endpoint**. Filtering along the route (ie: .filter().method(new MyFilter()) will break the batch-count-logic. Files that do not pass the filter will still be counted in CamelBatchSize! So if files aaa.txt, aa.txt and bb.txt are present at the 'from' endpoint, but only bb.txt should be processed, filtering using .filter() will only let bb.txt through but CamelBatchSize will still be 3 not 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can consume the file in the direct:OneFile route by using a pollEnrich (http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html). If you want you could set the file name as a header value in the counter bean and use it in the pollEnrich uri.

```
....
from(direct:OneFile)
    .pollEnrich(<your file uri with dynamic Expression containing filename>, 0, 
                    pollEnrichAggregationStrategy)
...
```